# Disable required CSRF in POST method in selected route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I have 4 router, where I need disable required CSRF in post (payments).

```
Route::post('createPayment', 'DotpayController@createPayment')->name('frontend.dotpay.createPayment');
Route::post('paymentConfirmation', 'DotpayController@paymentConfirmation')->name('frontend.paymentConfirmation');
Route::match(['POST', 'GET'], 'paymentConfirmationSplash', 'DotpayController@paymentConfirmationSplash')->name('frontend.paymentConfirmationSplash');
Route::get('/paymentStatus', 'DotpayController@paymentStatus')->name('frontend.paymentStatus')
```

How can I make it?

Comment: Is there any good reason to do this?

Answer (score 2):

VerifyCsrfToken middleware allows to specify routes that are excluded from CSRF validation.
**app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php** edit the except array to exclude some routes

```
protected $except = [
    'createPayment',
    'paymentConfirmation'
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the routes to **$except** array in your **App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php** class:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
  protected $except = [
    'createPayment/*',
    'paymentConfirmation/',
  ];
}
```

Comment: I try this code: protected $except = [
        'PaymentStatus/',
        'PaymentConfirmation/',
        'PaymentConfirmationSplash/',
        'CreatePayment/'
    ];

Comment: I have project in Laravel 7

Comment: I suggest you according to the Laravel 7 doc https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris may be there were a glitch, clear your route, cache config and try again

Answer (score 0):

exclude the routes by adding their URIs to the `$except` property of the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'createPayment',
        'paymentConfirmation',
        'paymentConfirmationSplash',
        
    ];
}
```